# find out if css of layer is block jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hide

I'm trying to figure a way of finding out if a layer is displayed or not

```
if ($('.property > .evenprop').css('display','block')){
    $('.otherprop').show();
    }
    else {
    $('.otherprop').hide();
    }
```

So something like if this is true

```
<div class="property">

<div class="evenprop" style="display:block">blah</div>

</div>
```

Then show this layer

```
<div class="otherprop">blahblah</div>

$('.otherprop').show();
```

Else if this is true

```
<div class="property">

<div class="evenprop" style="display:none">blah</div>

</div>
```

Then hide this layer

```
<div class="otherprop">blahblah</div>

$('.otherprop').hide();
```

Can't seem to get this to work though any ideas?

Thanks

Jamie

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're looking for the `:visible` pseudo-class.

```
if ($('.property > .evenprop').is(':visible')){
    $('.otherprop').show();
} else {
    $('.otherprop').hide();
}
```

The above can be reduced to

```
$('.otherprop').toggle($('.property > .evenprop').is(':visible'));
```

Answer (score 0):

`$('.property > .evenprop').css('display','block')` will set the CSS. If you need to check use [:visible](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/) selector

You can use something like this:

`if($('.property > .evenprop :visible').size!=0)`

Answer (score 0):

This would work too:

```
if ($('.property > .evenprop').css('display') == 'block'){ 
    //...
}
```